# Export Button in sales order grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, export, order-grid

I've included the following code in sales_order_grid.xml, but it's triggering a form key error. My goal is to export data to a text file. Could you please advise on how to accomplish this? Do I need to address the form key or a URL issue?

```
<exportButton>
    <settings>
        <options>
            <option name="txt" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">txt</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">TXT</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/index/index</item>
            </option>
        </options>
    </settings>
</exportButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to add the new export method **(txt)** in sales order grid export options.

**{vandor_module Path}/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                </item>
                <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>                          
                </item>
                <item name="txt" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">txt</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">txt</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">{{module}}/export/gridToTxt</item>                          
                </item>                     
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</exportButton>
```

**{vendor_module Path}\Model\Export\ConvertToTxt.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Export;


use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\SearchResultIteratorFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Convert\Excel;
use Magento\Framework\Convert\ExcelFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;


/**
 * Class ConvertToTxt
 */
class ConvertToTxt
{
    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $directory;


    /**
     * @var MetadataProvider
     */
    protected $metadataProvider;


    /**
     * @var ExcelFactory
     */
    protected $excelFactory;


    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;


    /**
     * @var SearchResultIteratorFactory
     */
    protected $iteratorFactory;


    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fields;


    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param MetadataProvider $metadataProvider
     * @param ExcelFactory $excelFactory
     * @param SearchResultIteratorFactory $iteratorFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Filter $filter,
        MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
        ExcelFactory $excelFactory,
        SearchResultIteratorFactory $iteratorFactory
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
        $this->excelFactory = $excelFactory;
        $this->iteratorFactory = $iteratorFactory;
    }


    /**
     * Returns Filters with options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->options) {
            $this->options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();
        }
        return $this->options;
    }


    /**
     * Returns DB fields list
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFields()
    {
        if (!$this->fields) {
            $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
            $this->fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
        }
        return $this->fields;
    }


    /**
     * Returns row data
     *
     * @param DocumentInterface $document
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRowData(DocumentInterface $document)
    {
        return $this->metadataProvider->getRowData($document, $this->getFields(), $this->getOptions());
    }


    /**
     * Returns TXT file
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getTxtFile()
    {
        $component = $this->filter->getComponent();


        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.txt';


        $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
        $this->filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider();


        $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->setLimit(0, 0);


        /** @var SearchResultInterface $searchResult */
        $searchResult = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getSearchResult();


        /** @var DocumentInterface[] $searchResultItems */
        $searchResultItems = $searchResult->getItems();


        $this->prepareItems($component->getName(), $searchResultItems);


        /** @var SearchResultIterator $searchResultIterator */
        $searchResultIterator = $this->iteratorFactory->create(['items' => $searchResultItems]);


        /** @var Excel $excel */
        $excel = $this->excelFactory->create([
            'iterator' => $searchResultIterator,
            'rowCallback'=> [$this, 'getRowData'],
        ]);


        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();


        $excel->setDataHeader($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
        $excel->write($stream, $component->getName() . '.txt');


        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();


        return [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $file,
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @param string $componentName
     * @param array $items
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareItems($componentName, array $items = [])
    {
        foreach ($items as $document) {
            $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($document, $componentName);
        }
    }
}
```

**{vendor_module Path}\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToTxt.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;


use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Export\ConvertToTxt;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;


/**
 * Class Render
 */
class GridToTxt extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var ConvertToTxt
     */
    protected $converter;


    /**
     * @var FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConvertToXml $converter
     * @param FileFactory $fileFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConvertToTxt $converter,
        FileFactory $fileFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->converter = $converter;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    }


    /**
     * Export data provider to XML
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->fileFactory->create('export.txt', $this->converter->getTxtFile(), 'var');
    }
}
```